# RSU vested recently

Tags: stocks

I am a non US citizen and have US RSU stock vested recently tax all cleared.
I have opened an account with ML but have no idea how to sell the stock, as I do not intend to hold such.
Additionally the shares decreased in value from the vesting date till reflected in my ML account by 40%?????
Any simple advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

ML is a brokerage firm. Tell them to sell. If you can't or don't know how to do it on-line - call them and do it over the phone.

Your citizenship might come in effect when tax are withheld, you need to fill form W8-BEN if you haven't done so yet. If US taxes are withheld, you can file 1040NR to request refund, or get it credited against your local tax liabilities.